# less: missing filename using execvp()

Tags: c, exec, argv, execvp

I am trying to use execvp() to run less however I keep running into the same error saying that:

```
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)
```

I'm assuming I am trying to input the file completely wrong. Could anyone give me some guidance? Here is my code line trying to implement it:

```
// args[0] == "tempFile" which is in my directory
execvp("less", args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as when you execute a shell script on the command line with

```
sh -c 'script body here' arg0 arg1 arg2
```

the `arg0` argument gets placed in `$0` (this is usually the name of the process) and is not really counted as one of the command line arguments of the script itself (it's not part of `$@` and `$#` will not count it).  The first command line argument available in `$1` is `arg1`.

In your case,  use `args[0] = "less"` and `args[1] = "tempFile"` in your C code. `args[3]` should be a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[0]` is meant to be the name you give to the command. The command you execute uses that to know how it was invoked. Typically, you'd want to use something like `less` here:

```
argv[0] = "less";
argv[1] = "filename";
argv[2] = NULL;
execvp("less", argv);
```

Comment: Clear and simple! Thanks! I'm trying my best to understand

Answer (score 1):

Argument 0, taken from `argv[0]`, is conventionally the command name. Typically it's the same string that you pass as the first argument to `execvp` (that's what shells do).

Argument 1, from `argv[1]`, is the first “real” argument. So pass a 3-element array containing: `char *args[] = {"less", "tempFile", NULL}`

Most languages follow the same argument numbering. For example, if you invoke a shell script, it sees what you pass as `argv[0]` as its `$0`, what you pass as `argv[1]` as `$1`, etc. Perl is a notable exception: in a Perl script, `argv[0]` is `$0`, `argv[1]` is `$ARGV[0]`, `argv[2]` is `$ARGV[1]`, etc.